# Form is not being saved in Django admin page

Tags: python, django

I have faced a problem in my Django project where my form is not being saved as a new listing in my model(listing) and is not even showing on Django's admin page.

my models.py :

```
class listing(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    describtion = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    bid = models.FloatField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(categories, default=1, verbose_name="Category", 
              on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,default='', verbose_name="User", on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title} "
```

create a new listing form :

```
        
class create(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = listing
        fields = [ 'title', 'describtion','bid','category','image']
```

views.py :

```
def CreateListing(request):
    user = request.user
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = create(request.POST, instance=user)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_listing = form.save()
            new_listing.user = request.user
            new_listing.save()
        return render(request, "auctions/listing.html")
    else:
        return render(request, "auctions/Create.html",{
            "form": create
        })
```

Ps: I have no problem with my urls.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the user *before* you can save this to the database:

```
def CreateListing(request):
    user = request.user
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = create(request.POST, instance=user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.user = user
            form.save()
            return redirect('%name-of-some-view')
    else:
        form = create(instance=user)
    return render(request, "auctions/Create.html",{
        'form': form
    })
```

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

---

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
> [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
> to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
> This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
> browser.

Comment: thanks for your feedback, the problem was fixed by changing the form variable into this form `form = create(request.POST, request.FILES)` and `form.instance.user = user` before saving.